# What difference between this two 328i?

Tags: bmw, 328i

BWM enjoyers. Looking for 2013 328i as my first BMW. In some advertisements for sale, these cars do not look as cool as in photos from the Internet. Therefore, the question arose: how (besides color, of course) do the two cars below differ? Is the first one photographed from a bad angle, or is the body shape still slightly different? Thank you, and sorry for the possibly stupid, but important question of the day.

[image]

[image]

Comment: They look like the same car to me. Sure, the angle is a little different in the top one (and the slight tilt of the wheels makes it look jazzier), but the big difference is the background makes the car 'pop' more in the photo. Good photographers make money for a reason.

Comment: Two difference I see between the two cars is the front facia (near the fog lamps) and the wheels. I don't have a clue what either difference means, but thought I'd point it out.

Comment: I found images in a google search showing me the top car looks like a [2013 320i](https://vehicle-images.dealerinspire.com/7481-110004126/WBA3B1C56DK128769/1415e259b52366f8ea20b3848e3732b4.jpg) while the bottom one looks like a [2013 328i](https://www.cars.com/research/bmw-328-2013/) ... looks like the top one would have a smaller engine than the other one. This accounts for the two different wheels and front facia.